# Chrome devtools appends ".download" to my js files with I save the webpage with assets

Tags: web, google-chrome-devtools

I work as Product Manager for a SASS company. Our website is fully developed in-house. We use Chrome devtools as a pseudo-IDE to create prototypes for upper management, as part of creating a functional spec for a project.

Our workflow consists of saving a page with assets from our application, then modifying the HTML and CSS in devtools, and adding any JavaScript if needed.

When you save a page with Chrome, it downloads all of the assets locally. It has worked great in the past, but recently Chrome started appending a ".download" extension to JavaScript files only. This causes the JS files to be duplicated in the assets folder. It also changes the file path in the HTML head to point to the ".download" JS files instead. I can fix it manually, but once I save the page with assets again, Chrome does it again.

Is there anyway I can prevent Chrome from doing that?

[image: HTML Head]

[image: Files in Asset Folder]

Comment: Look into some of the chrome extensions that do this. You might find one that is better for your workflow in many ways

Comment: Try using [devtools `Workspaces`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We primarily use the DOM inspector to make modifications to the structure of the page because the HTML document is very large and messy. The workflow we've used thus far has worked great. I'm more interested in finding out how to prevent Chrome from duplicating my resources.

Comment: It's either a bug or "security" feature. There's nothing we can do about it other than submitting a bug report on https://crbug.com and meanwhile you can write a shell script or batch file that renames the files properly.